# NativeScript RFID Plugin for Android

Tags: javascript, typescript, nativescript, rfid, nativescript-plugin

I want to know if any NativeScript Plugin is Available for Zebra RFID Devices, I am not getting any Plugin Related to RFID at the Nativescript developer platform, Please let me know if you have any helpful information with you.

I have searched everywhere on the Internet, including the native script Developer platform but haven't found any satisfactory solution for my problem.

looking forward to your response :)

Thanks!